# Regex to match empty div pairs containing spaces?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove all empty div tag pairs containing white spaces.

```html
<div class="elementor-form-fields-wrapper elementor-labels-above">
    <div class="elementor-field-type-email elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-email elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
    <label for="form-field-email" class="elementor-field-label">Email</label>
    <input size="1" type="email" name="form_fields[email]" id="form-field-email" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Email" required="required" aria-required="true">               </div>
                                <div>
                                    </div>
                                
            </div>
```

I tried following regex but it matches all tags. I just need div tags.

```php
$content = preg_replace('/<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|"[^"]*"|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*\/?>\s*<\/\1\s*>/', '', $content);
```

**Note:** I don't want to use any parser for now. Those genius mark the question closed without reading the entire question, please care to comment.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RegEx**

```
<div\s*>\s*<\/div>
<div\s*>               : Match an opening <div> tag with 0 or more spaces between the word and closing >
        \s*            : Match 0 or more white space characters between the tags
            <\/div>    : Match a closing </div> tag (/ is escaped)
```

**Working Example**

```
$string = '
<div class="elementor-form-fields-wrapper elementor-labels-above">
    <div class="elementor-field-type-email elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-email elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
    <label for="form-field-email" class="elementor-field-label">Email</label>
    <input size="1" type="email" name="form_fields[email]" id="form-field-email" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Email" required="required" aria-required="true">
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>';



$out = preg_replace("/<div>\s*<\/div>/", "", $string);

echo $out;

/*
  Output:

    <div class="elementor-form-fields-wrapper elementor-labels-above">
        <div class="elementor-field-type-email elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-email elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required">
            <label for="form-field-email" class="elementor-field-label">Email</label>
            <input size="1" type="email" name="form_fields[email]" id="form-field-email" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Email" required="required" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Pease not the div tag contains space

Comment: @SkyRar what do you mean when you say the div tag contains space? This **does** work if you copy/paste this into a php file and execute?

Comment: I tried your solution. Please have a look here https://paiza.io/projects/WzNRVkXxafAlC8PTenf3pA . I think it is not space but may be line break or something.

Comment: I noticed in the link it works but in browser the div is still there. I can ensure you that I cleared cache and all. However when I use the regex that I mentioned in my question works perfectly. I have updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: It seems with entire html structure it doesn't work. I updated the link https://paiza.io/projects/WzNRVkXxafAlC8PTenf3pA . You can see the empty div if you ctrl+f  `form-field-email`

Comment: That is simply because the `<div>` tag has a space before the `>` i.e. `<div >`. I'll update the answer